# Textview with global variable

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I simply called the global variable on the Textview object and printed it out, but I got the following error

How can I run the following code normally?

p.s.textread_buf is global variable.

---

logcat

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sentence_app, PID: 26177

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

    at com.example.sentence_app.senten_check_example_mean.onCreateView(senten_check_example_mean.java:40)
```

---

//error code

```
public class senten_check_example_mean extends Fragment {

    public static senten_check_example_mean newInstance(){

        return new senten_check_example_mean();

    }

    public senten_check_example_mean() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    Button return_sentence_check_button;

    TextView textView_name ;
    TextView textView_mean ;
    TextView textView_example ;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        textView_name =(TextView) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.text_read_name);
        textView_mean =(TextView) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.text_read_mean);
        textView_example =(TextView) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.text_read_example);

        textView_name.setText(((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).textread_buf.getSentence_name());
        textView_mean.setText(((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).textread_buf.getSentence_example());
        textView_example.setText(((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).textread_buf.getSentence_mean());

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_senten_check_example_mean, container, false);
    }

}
```

//textread.class

```
package com.example.sentence_app;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.Queue;

import java.util.Stack;

public class textread {

    String sentence_name;
    String sentence_example;
    Queue<String> sentence_mean;

    textread(){

    }

    textread(String temp){
        String []cs = temp.split("\\|");
        this.setSentence_name(cs[0]);
        this.setSentence_mean(cs[1]);
        this.setSentence_example(cs[2]);
    }

    public String getSentence_example() {
        return sentence_example;
    }

    public String getSentence_mean() {
        return sentence_mean.peek();
    }

    public String getSentence_name() {
        return sentence_name;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do the same implementation in onViewCreated. You will get view as parameter in onViewCreated use that to initialize the view. like view.findViewById(R.id.text_read_name); this would work

Comment: these textviews like id ```text_read_name``` are inside your fragment layout ```fragment_senten_check_example_mean``` right?

Answer (score 1):

This question will ultimately be closed as a duplicate for null pointer exception.. nevertheless, if these textviews are inside your fragment layout like normal then try refactoring your fragment `onCreateView` as below:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_senten_check_example_mean, container, false);

        textView_name =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_read_name);
        textView_mean =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_read_mean);
        textView_example =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_read_example);

        textView_name.setText(((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).textread_buf.getSentence_name());
        textView_mean.setText(((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).textread_buf.getSentence_example());
        textView_example.setText(((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).textread_buf.getSentence_mean());

        return view;
    }
```

You need to inflate the layout view first, then find your views in that inflated layout. Finding those views inside activity won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

First You change textview initializing onCreateView to onViewCreated method because it is not good to practise and some time View did not inflate so initialize your variable in onViewCreated method okay then recompile code.

Comment: like this?

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        TextView textView_name =(TextView) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.text_read_name);
        
TextView textView_mean =(TextView) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.text_read_mean);
        
TextView textView_example =(TextView) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.text_read_example);

Comment: @Marok Can you share complete error I mean in details

Answer (score 0):

First, move your findViewbyId() to onViewCreated

Second, its not working because you use getActivity() (get the parent activity) to find a view in fragment xml. Use getView().findViewById() or use inflater instead